# Is Style Inheritence with nested User Controls Possible In WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to use `BasedOn` with regards to a `Style` declaration in a nested `UserControl`, and be able to reference a `Style` declaration made in a parent `UserControl` - can anyone confirm this?

I've tried `BasedOn="{StaticResource}"` and `BasedOn="{DynamicResource}"` and neither work.

(Pseudo code sample below)

```
<Window>
  <UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
      </StackPanel.Resources>
     <UserControl2> <!--this will reside in a different .xaml file...-->
       <Button Content="Hello World">
         <Button.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="????"> 
           <!--is this possible to inherit the red background?-->
             <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
           </Style>
         </Button.Style>
       </Button>
     </UserControl2>
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl
```

Comment: @Clemens - this will refer to a style located in my `App.xaml` master resource dictionary, rather than the  hierarchically closest 'red background' style.

Comment: It's a pity they didn't make styles cascade.   Resources have scope. So you could maybe have a style in a parent control with a key then reference that key in a control in the visual tree within that. Or you could go find the source for basedon and write your own markup extension inspired by that code. Or you could extend your usercontrol and add a dp to that. The usercontrol could go find a style out a parent.

Comment: Add new style in resources and make based on parent then attach that to target element. @maxp

Comment: @Tigran - This is in the main App.xaml resources? I figure this would work, but it's a shame as I don't really want to tweak this for such an edge case.

Comment: @maxp - it is not necessary in App.xaml resources, in window resources. Sorry what is the your main goal?